# RabbitMQ: Cannot see queues from the admin page

Tags: rabbitmq

From the rabbitMQ main page, I could see there are 8 queues, but when I switch to queue page, there is none. I logged in using the admin account.[image]
[image]

The other tabs are showing correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem before.  I solved it by restarting the application(s) reading from the queues.

Comment: I tried and it didn't work for me.